# How to define a VectorXd array in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to define a `VectorXd` array in `Eigen`, the following are my code

```
void function(VectorXd * b, ...)
{
    [snippet]
    vector<VectorXd(b->rows())> xs(max_iter+1);
    [snippet]
}
```

So, I want to define an array whose length is `max_iter+1` and every element in the array is a `3X1` VectorXd.

But when it was compiled, it returned the following error:

```
/path/to/solutions.h:187: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
     vector<VectorXd(b->rows())> xs(max_iter+1);
                                  ^
/path/to/solutions.h:187: error: 'b' cannot appear in a constant-expression
     vector<VectorXd(b->rows())> xs(max_iter+1);
                     ^
```

What shoud I do to fix these bugs? Thank you!

Comment: what does `b` look like? how do you call this function?

Comment: @kangshiyin, `b` is a column vector which type if `VectorXd` in Eigen.

Comment: but `VectorXd` does not have a member function named `.row()`

Comment: @kangshiyin, sorry, my fault, it is `rows()`, I want to get the dimension of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work on `std::vector` of `int`, you use

```
std::vector<int> xs(size, init_value);
```

Similarly, it should be something like this when you work on `std::vector` of `VectorXd`.

```
std::vector<VectorXd> xs(max_iter+1, VectorXd(b->rows()));
```

It has to be a type name between `< >`, but you use an object `VectorXd(b->rows())`.

Comment: Thank you, I know what should I do now.